# How do I animate Sprites in Unity JavaScript?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm learning **unityscript** for **Unity 3D**. I'm new to programming (one month old) and I'm building a 2D game that is going pretty good so far.

[**Cubical Chimera**](http://thebrokenlimits.com/bl/Games.html)

My code (game not updated in the above example) allows the character to cycle through from shooting position (shown in game) and standing, when the Left-CTRL button is pressed ("Shoot").

I need a Much better method.

How do I program sprite sheets *Correctly* using **unityscript** in **Unity 3D**?

```
   var numFrames    : int = 2;
   function Update () 
   {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Shoot"))
       {        
        renderer.material.mainTextureOffset.x += 1.0 / numFrames;
       }
    }
```

There's more, but this shows the crummy sprite animation I have conjured up. Please help...

Answer (score 1):

http://walkerboystudio.com/html/unity_course_lab_3.html

Go down to part 14 and on. That should be what you're looking for. It helped me a lot!

If that doesn't work, try this:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Animating_Tiled_texture

Comment: Please summarize the helpful information in this answer. If links change or break, this answer loses all context. Try to avoid link only answers in the future. This has been flagged for removal, please edit soon or it will likely be deleted.